# How to process telegram messages in parallel using pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

```
from pyrogram import Client

app = Client(client_name, api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

async def handle_messages(client, message):
    await some_other_function()

app.run()
```

If multiple messages are received together, it seems to process them one by one. How can I process multiple messages in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

If some_other_function() is CPU intensive and not I/O intensive then to get true parallelism you need to implement multiprocessing or multithreading that being said the issue here might only be I/O wait time so you may still handle multiple messages pretty efficiently using asynchronous code only. instead of awaiting the some_other_function. you just create a task and just let it run. asynchronous co routines start executing immediately after task is created. so use

```
asyncio.create_task(some_other_function(message))
```